# CTRL+F shortcut for clicking arrow down/up

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, shortcut, ctrl

in the browser like chrome, there is a shortcut called <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

the problem that sometimes I don't find directly what I want so I click the arrow

[image]

yes it work fine, but **I want to use a shortcut also for that**.

---

I tried to click UP_ARROW nothing will happen.
DOWN_ARROW as well.

---

this will be useful as well on VS CODE (ide for programming since they have the same shortcut as browser)

---

#### so what I want

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. [image]
3. if now I am in 3/71, next 4/71 on clicking shortcut (without mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <kbd>TAB</kbd> to highlight the up chevron

and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to find the next occurrence.

One more <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get to the down chevron.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to move in the other direction (left).

---

For your example, to show the 4th/71, it would be <kbd>TAB</kbd>,<kbd>TAB</kbd>,<kbd>SPACE</kbd>